# estimate for a solution in some norm

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Consider the following problem

$-(x^2+1)u''-2xu'=\sin(2\pi x), \;x \in (0,1)$

$u(0)=0$, $u(1)=0$.
I want to show that there exists a unique solution $u \in H^1_0(0,1)$ and find an estimate for
$\|u'\|_{L^2(0,1)}$

Here is the solution:
[image]

I have a few questions: What is $a_{ij}$ ? Is it $-(x^2+1)$? and if so how does that form a matrix?
Is it possible to prove uniqueness by using Lax-Milgram?

I don't understand the integrating by parts. What is our $u$ and $dv$?

Why are we inner producting with u? Shouldn't we use a test function but then again it is stated that u is in $H^1_0(0,1)$. I'd still like an answer on this, if possible

Finally the lines after the Cauchy Schwarz inequality are a bit mysterious.
Please shed some light on it.

And it looks like the problem was written incorrectly. Is should be find an estimate $||u'||_{H^1_0(0,1)}$ but I could be wrong

If you have a different solution that you would like to share, please feel free to do so

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $u_1$ and $u_2$ on $[0, 1]$  both satisfy
$$0 = (x^2 + 1)u''(x) + 2xu'(x) + \sin(2\pi x)$$
on $(0, 1)$ with the boundary conditions $u(0) = u(1) = 0$.
Then $w := u_1 - u_2$ satisfies
\begin{align}
0 &= (x^2 + 1)w''(x) + 2xw'(x) \\
&= ((x^2 + 1)w'(x))'
\end{align}
with $w(0) = w(1) = 0$. This shows $(x^2 + 1) w'(x)$ is a constant, say $C$, and that
$$ w(1) = w(0) + C \int_0^1 (x^2 + 1)^{-1} dx.$$
You know that $w(0) = 0$, that the integrand is positive on $(0, 1)$, so the only possible way you'll get $w(1) = 0$ is if $C = 0$.

You might consider more generally the ODE $u''(x) + b(x)u'(x) = f(x)$, where $b$ and $f$ are continuous on $[0, 1]$, same boundary conditions. With $u_1$ and $u_2$ also satisfying these, again set $w := u_1 - u_2$. Using the integrating factor $I(x) := \exp(\int_0^x b(\xi)d\xi)$ you can write
\begin{align}
0 &= w''(x) + b(x)w'(x) \\
  &= (I(x)w'(x))'/I(x)
\end{align}
and use the same trick to show $w = 0$.

All that being said, I understand it doesn't really answer the question about weak solutions, in this case in $H^1_0(0, 1)$, being unique.

Your original ODE can be written in the form $au'' + a'u' = f$, and for any $v \in H^1_0(0,1)$ you have
$(au'' + a'u')v = fv$. Integrating over $(0, 1)$ you get
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 fv &= \int_0^1 (au'' + a'u')v \\
&= \int_0^1 (au')'v \\
&= \int_0^1 (au'v)' - \int_0^1 au'v' \\
&= -\int_0^1 au'v'.
\end{align}
which provides a weak formulation.
Doing the $w := u_1 - u_2$ trick again you find $w$ has to satisfy
$$ 0 = \int_0^1 a w'v'.$$
The specific choice $v = w$ shows $\int_0^1 a (w')^2 = 0$.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing here. Can you explain how you got the relationship between $w(0)$ and $w(1)$? Also the expression with the integration factor. In the third line of your string of integral inequalities, is the first term correct? Also what was the point of all of this. Are you showing that w=0?